# Dependency Injection of non-concurrency safe dependencies for a net/HTTP server

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I am playing around with Dependency Injection and HTTP servers in Golang, and are trying to wrap my head around how to make available a logger that contains information related to the current request that is being handled. What I want to be able to do is to call a logging function inside the current `http.Handler` and functions/methods that is being called inside from the `http.Handler`. Essentially leave a request ID in every log event, so I can trace exactly what happened.

My idea was to use Dependency Injection and define all the logic as methods on interfaces that would have the logger injected. I like this approach, since it makes the dependencies painstakingly clear.

I've seen other approaches, such as Zerolog's hlog package that puts the logger into the requests `context.Context`, and I could then modify my code to receive a `context.Context` as an argument, from where I could pull out the logger and call it. While this will work, I don't like it very much, in that it kinda hides away the dependency.

My issue is that I can't seem to come up with a way of using Dependency Injection in conjunction with a HTTP handling server, where the injected dependencies are concurrency safe.

As an example, I whipped up this code (ignore the fact that it doesn't use interfaces)

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    mrand "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    l := LoggingService{}
    ss := SomethingService{
        LoggingService: &l,
    }
    handler := Handler{
        SomethingService: &ss,
        LoggingService:   &l,
    }

    http.Handle("/", &handler)

    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:3333", nil)
}

type Handler struct {
    SomethingService *SomethingService
    LoggingService   *LoggingService
}

func (h *Handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    reqID := generateRequestID()
    h.LoggingService.AddRequestID(reqID)
    h.LoggingService.Log("A request")
    out := h.SomethingService.DoSomething("nothing")
    w.Write([]byte(out))
}

func generateRequestID() string {
    buf := make([]byte, 10)
    rand.Read(buf)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", buf)
}

type SomethingService struct {
    LoggingService *LoggingService
}

func (s *SomethingService) DoSomething(input string) string {
    s.LoggingService.Log(fmt.Sprintf("Let's do something with %s", input))
    mrand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    n := mrand.Intn(3)
    s.LoggingService.Log(fmt.Sprintf("Sleeping %d seconds...", n))
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(n) * time.Second)
    s.LoggingService.Log("Done")

    return "something"
}

type LoggingService struct {
    RequestID string
}

func (l *LoggingService) AddRequestID(id string) {
    l.RequestID = id
}

func (l *LoggingService) Log(msg string) {
    if l.RequestID != "" {
        fmt.Printf("[%s] %s\n", l.RequestID, msg)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", msg)
    }
}
```

The way that I've understood Go's HTTP server is that the handler is invoked, for each request, in it's own goroutine. Because the LoggingService is passed as a pointer, each of these goroutines are essentially accessing the same instance of LoggingService, which can result in a race condition where one request sets `l.RequestID` after which another request logs its requests, but ends up with the request ID from the first request.

I am sure others have run into a need to log something in a function that is called by a HTTP request and to be able to trace that log event to that specific request? However, I haven't found any examples where people are doing this.

I was thinking of delaying the instantiation of the dependencies until inside the handler. While that works, it has the side-effect of creating many instances of the dependencies - This is fine for the LoggingService, but something like the SomethingService could be talking to a DB, where it would be a waste to create a database client for every request (since most DB implementations have concurrency safe clients).

Comment: If the things you inject are not themselves concurrency-safe, you must take additional precautions to serialise access (perhaps using a mutex) to them.

Comment: It just doesn't seem right to have to use a mutex for request scoped logging?

Comment: Are you sure the logger itself isn't concurrency-safe?

Comment: The logger itself is concurrency safe - I was planning on using Zerolog, which is concurrency safe as far as I know. But I still run into these 2 issues: Adding the request ID to the logger for the duration of the request and making the logger (with the request ID) available to functions called during the request.

Comment: @MadsRC in general dependencies need not be request-specific, that also means that those dependencies ought not be put into the context. If the logger needs the request id then simply put the request id into the context and pass the context to the logger, and whatever else cares about it.

Comment: @MadsRC when you truly need a request specific dependency (e.g., a db transaction), then, given your "painstakingly clear" approach, you have no other option then what you've already spelled out in the last paragraph, however the per-request dependency "instantiation" does not have to be prohibitive, simply create a shallow copy and update only those values that need to be request specific.

Comment: context is THE request-specific data holder, adding a logger (and other request-specific info) to the context in middleware and later extracting it where needed works fine